# How can I download an installed extension from my magento site

Tags: php, magento

I want to move my existing Magento site (ver 1.6) to another hosting for some reason. I have upgraded my Magento to ver 1.9 and have installed the theme as well. The only issue now is to install the extensions that I was using previously but I cannot find a few of them again to download them (free ones). So can't I just copy my extensions from the previous site and then install them again on my new setup(new hosting Magento ver 1.9)

Comment: let me know if you find any other problems

Comment: Sure! Trying your solution. Hope it works! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to to root of the site, than go for this path :

below "app" folder , you can see "Downloader" folder. go to below path

`downloader/.cache/community` here you can see all the extensions you can see in .tgz format, you can download to your local system. later you can use software to convert from .tgz format to normal folders.